# How do I convert an integer to decimal in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a number in JavaScript that I'd like to convert to a money format:

```
556633 -> £5566.33
```

How do I do this in JavaScript?

Answer (score 56):

Try this:

```
var num = 10;
var result = num.toFixed(2); // result will equal string "10.00"
```

Comment: +1 for ensuring 2 decimal places (plus toFixed also handles rounding)

Comment: +1, to improve, you may ensure that it returns a number with a parseFloat rather than a string

Comment: Be aware of the fact that this outputs a string.

Comment: how to get the typeof to be number but still retain the trailing zero; Example parseFloat(3.6 + 4.4).toFixed(1) output to be number => 8.0 than string "8.0"

Answer (score 17):

This works:

```
var currencyString = "£" + (amount/100).toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
"£"+556633/100
```

Comment: I'd say `"£" + (556633 / 100)` to be sure.

Comment: Works for this *exact* case, but how about if the number 556633.9 was fed in. Then it gives too many decimal places.

Comment: You are right Rob Levine, if OP want 2 decimal places, need to do .toFixed(2), but there is answers for that already, I wouldn't update my answer.

Answer (score 4):

This script making only integer to decimal. 
Seperate the thousands

```
onclick='alert(MakeDecimal(123456789));' 


function MakeDecimal(Number) {
        Number = Number + "" // Convert Number to string if not
        Number = Number.split('').reverse().join(''); //Reverse string
        var Result = "";
        for (i = 0; i <= Number.length; i += 3) {
            Result = Result + Number.substring(i, i + 3) + ".";
        }
        Result = Result.split('').reverse().join(''); //Reverse again
        if (!isFinite(Result.substring(0, 1))) Result = Result.substring(1, Result.length); // Remove first dot, if have.
        if (!isFinite(Result.substring(0, 1))) Result = Result.substring(1, Result.length); // Remove first dot, if have.
        return Result;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using template literals you can achieve this:

```
const num = 556633;
const formattedNum = `${num/100}.00`;
console.log(formattedNum);
```